# Doctrine Table Copy

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm

Is there a straightforward way to copy a table in Doctrine similar to, for example, MySQL's CREATE TABLE/SELECT copy?:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_database2.my_table SELECT * FROM my_database1.my_table
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Doctrine DBAL CLI tool `dbal:run-sql` to execute arbitrary SQL directly from the command line.

This should be capable of executing your SQL statement, although in my experience, if you can alter your database from the CLI anyway, the effect would be about the same as using `mysql` directly.

If I've misunderstood your goal, please explain a little more about what you're trying to do and I'll be happy to revise.

Comment: Right now I'm using a simple $conn->executeQuery() to run the above MySQL-specific query.  I was wondering if there was a database-independent way to achieve the above with Doctrine.